# How to access elements within a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

UPDATE: JSFiddle linked below has been updated.  This recreates the problem.

Question now edited as requested: code is in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdelgreco/zh3h8474/7/).

The `toggleFundingType()` function returns false at all times.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please so that we can see/reproduce the issue? A jsFiddle or stack snippet would help.

Comment: There's nothing magic about a jquery ui dialog, it's just a div located in the dom. If your function isn't finding the checkbox, it isn't part of the dom or doesn't match the selector (in your example, it would match the selector.) At this point, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Maybe you should try breaking down your selector and see what works, use some console.log in your function. $('input').length $('input[name=funding_type]').length etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I ended up using the [Firefox plugin FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), which gives you the best jQuery selectors when you mouse over elements.

Here is the [JSFiddle with the working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdelgreco/zh3h8474/9/).

It all boiled down to selecting the radio buttons one at a time, with input and then the element id,  like:

```
$('input#funding_type_encumbrance')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code working perfectly Check [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3orc680m/)

Alternatively you can use following code (I changed selector just to be sure about the encumbrance radio button)

```
function firstButtonIsChecked() {
     if ($("#my_dialog :radio[value=encumbrance]").is(":checked")) {
          return true;
     }
     else {
          return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why would changing the selector make a difference?

Comment: Changing the selector would make a huge difference if the current selector was picking up a different element.